# Android - zoom in/out RelativeLayout with spread/pinch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an activity with a `RelativeLayout` and a private class in it, which extends the `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`. In the `onScale` method of the listener I'd like to zoom in/out of the whole layout (everything the user sees) with the user spreading/pinching his fingers.

I'd like the changes to the layout NOT to be permanent, i.e. when the spread/pinch gesture is over I'd like the layout to go back to what it was in first place (any resetting could be done in the `onScaleEnd` method of the `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` for example).

I've tried to implement it via calling `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` on the `RelativeLayout` and also by using a `ScaleAnimation`. Neither resulted in smooth zooming (or anything that could at all be called zooming). Is it even possible to zoom in/out a `RelativeLayout`?

The only idea I have left would be reading a screenshot from the cache and putting it as an `ImageView` on top of the whole layout and the zoom in/out of this image via `setImageMatrix`. I have no clue, however, how to implement this.

May layout also contains a container for a fragment, which is empty at the time the zooming is supposed to be possible. In the `onScaleEnd` gesture, the fragment is put into it's container (already implemented and working fine). Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_pinch"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >   


<!-- Layout containing the thumbnail ImageViews -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail_group_pui"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c3"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c4"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c6"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tn_c7"/>

</LinearLayout>


<!-- Layout containing the dashed boxes -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="152dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dashed_box"/>

</LinearLayout>


<!-- Container for the fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_pui"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**
I found these two related topics:
[Extending RelativeLayout, and overriding dispatchDraw() to create a zoomable ViewGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378904/extending-relativelayout-and-overriding-dispatchdraw-to-create-a-zoomable-vie)
[Zoom Content in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192424/zoom-content-in-a-relativelayout)

I did not get the implementation, however. What other methods do I have to include in the extended class to actually scale the layout or reset it?

Comment: to zoom a layout how do we use `ZoomableRelativeLayout`? Do i need to pass my view as a parameter to its constructor?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So I created a subclass of `RelativeLayout` as described in the above mentioned topics. It looks like this:

```
public class ZoomableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
float mScaleFactor = 1;
float mPivotX;
float mPivotY;

public ZoomableRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ZoomableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ZoomableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mPivotX, mPivotY);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void scale(float scaleFactor, float pivotX, float pivotY) {
    mScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    mPivotX = pivotX;
    mPivotY = pivotY;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void restore() {
    mScaleFactor = 1;
    this.invalidate();
}

}
```

My implementation of the `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` looks like this:

```
private class OnPinchListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    float startingSpan; 
    float endSpan;
    float startFocusX;
    float startFocusY;


    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        startingSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
        startFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
        startFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mZoomableRelativeLayout.scale(detector.getCurrentSpan()/startingSpan, startFocusX, startFocusY);
        return true;
    }

    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mZoomableRelativeLayout.restore();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

### Update:

You can integrate `OnPinchListener` for your `ZoomableRelativelayout` by using `ScaleGestureDetector`:

```
ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new OnPinchListener());
```

And you are required to bind touch listener of Zoomable layout with the touch listener of ScaleGestureDetector:

```
mZoomableLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: how to apply this `OnPinchListener` to RelativeLayout.

Comment: To apply onPinchListner I think you need to implement onTouch where you need to specify   mOnPinchListener.onTouchEvent(ev);

Comment: what mZoomableRelativeLayout variable means?

Comment: It's the ZoomableRelativeLayout instance

Comment: hi thanks @Schnodahipfe can u please tell me how to implement OnPinchListener to RelativeLayout

Comment: @Schnodahipfe Your solution only scales the canvas and not the View itself. You need to transform all the touch points and clip rects of the children for it to be complete. what bugs is that setScaleX/Y does that for you but i stymied as to why the zoom is not smooth.

Comment: It seems many are having queries regarding implementing OnPinchListener for ZoomableRelativeLayout and for the same I have **updated code**! Cheers

Comment: @Schnodahipfe : I implemented your above classes, and the relative layout is zooming perfect. But I want to hold the zoomed out/in view after removing fingers from screen. So for this I remove the " mZoomableRelativeLayout.restore();" from "onScaleEnd" function. This works perfect. But problem is the touch of the elements in that relative layout doesn't get update, as they still remains at the position when they are present when "mScaleFactor" of relative layout is 1. Please Help....Need to update touches of buttons inside relative layout along with zoom in/out.

Comment: how to apply move event to this custom relative view

Comment: Do I need to create the OnPinchListener in ZoomableRelativeLayout and how zoomableRelativeLayout Object is created?

Comment: Awesome Functionality..
Done with my Relative Layout

Comment: Pinch zoom in/out not working properly. When I try to pinch zoom in/out its like zooming in something and going back to normal.

Comment: how to restrict zoom out or zoom in @PareshMayani

Comment: I found out  if (detector.getCurrentSpan() <= startingSpan) {
    relMain.scale(detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan, startFocusX, startFocusY);
   }

Comment: how to pass the Layout i want to zoom to this class?

Comment: grabbing a hold of startingSpan and later dividing for the scale just saved my day. thank you.

Comment: @NavjotBedi can you or Schnodahipfe share your xml and activity snippet, because i tried this approach but couldn't even get the error free compilation. I need this thing badly so please if you can share this thing, it will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: how it goes with my Activity? Relative layout has many views and it is a part of the activity. How `layout_pinch` will be zoomed by using `ZoomableRelativeLayout` ????

Comment: @Schnodahipfe , If you don't want your layout to restore, simply comment the line thats says mZoomableRelativeLayout.restore(); in the OnPinchListener class.
excellnt answer

Comment: This is not making zoom again from the same size(zoomed value which already zoomed by pinching) of the layout, its pinching works perfect.Please tell me what should i update in this code do so ?

Answer (score 19):

Create class called Zoomlayout which extends any layout that you want to zoom in my case it is Relative Layout.

```
public class ZoomLayout extends RelativeLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

private enum Mode {
   NONE,
   DRAG,
   ZOOM
 }

 private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
 private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
 private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 4.0f;

 private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
 private float scale = 1.0f;
 private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

 // Where the finger first  touches the screen
 private float startX = 0f;
 private float startY = 0f;

 // How much to translate the canvas
 private float dx = 0f;
 private float dy = 0f;
 private float prevDx = 0f;
 private float prevDy = 0f;

 public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
   super(context);
   init(context);
 }

 public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   init(context);
 }

 public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   init(context);
 }

 public void init(Context context) {
   final ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
   this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
       switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
           if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
             mode = Mode.DRAG;
             startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
             startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
           }
           break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
             dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
             dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
           }
           break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
           mode = Mode.ZOOM;
           break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
           mode = Mode.DRAG;
           break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           Log.i(TAG, "UP");
           mode = Mode.NONE;
           prevDx = dx;
           prevDy = dy;
           break;
       }
       scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

       if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
         getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
         float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
         float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale))/ 2 * scale;
         dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
         dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
         Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
           + ", max " + maxDx);
         applyScaleAndTranslation();
       }

       return true;
     }
   });
 }

 // ScaleGestureDetector

 @Override
 public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
   Log.i(TAG, "onScaleBegin");
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
   float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
   Log.i(TAG, "onScale" + scaleFactor);
   if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
     scale *= scaleFactor;
     scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
     lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
   } else {
     lastScaleFactor = 0;
   }
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
   Log.i(TAG, "onScaleEnd");
 }

 private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
   child().setScaleX(scale);
   child().setScaleY(scale);
   child().setTranslationX(dx);
   child().setTranslationY(dy);
 }

 private View child() {
   return getChildAt(0);
 }

}
```

After this add ZoomLayout in xml that has only one child.For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.focusmedica.digitalatlas.headandneck.ZoomLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/zoomLayout"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="Heading"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvSubtitle2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivOn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivOff"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/off_txt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivOn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/on_txt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pinOn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pinOn" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pinOff"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pin_off"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pinOn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pin_on"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivOff"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivOff" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/wait"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/fullIVideo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/wait"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/colorCode"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/wait"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/labelText"/>

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/download"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/label_play"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fullIVideo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/up"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_frame"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelDescription" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/up"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/up" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.focusmedica.digitalatlas.headandneck.ZoomLayout>
```

Now in MainActivity create object of ZoomLayout and define id.Like

```
ZoomLayout zoomlayout= findViewbyId(R.id.zoomLayout);
zoomlayout.setOnTouchListener(FullScreenVideoActivity.this);
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     linear.init(FullScreenVideoActivity.this);
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: what is linear in this line
linear.init(FullScreenVideoActivity.this);

Comment: @AwaisMajeed ZoomLayout

Comment: I don't think you need init call inside on touch it also works when it is outside bellow findViewById

Comment: How to temporarily disable this zoom feature programatically without removing it from layout?

Comment: Is it possible to put some  child view on some fix cordinate position without  zooming

Answer (score 6):

I think I managed to improve Schnodahipfe's answer a little bit. I added two methods to the ZoomableRelativeLayout class.

```
public void relativeScale(float scaleFactor, float pivotX, float pivotY)
{
    mScaleFactor *= scaleFactor;

    if(scaleFactor >= 1)
    {
        mPivotX = mPivotX + (pivotX - mPivotX) * (1 - 1 / scaleFactor);
        mPivotY = mPivotY + (pivotY - mPivotY) * (1 - 1 / scaleFactor);
    }
    else
    {
        pivotX = getWidth()/2;
        pivotY = getHeight()/2;

        mPivotX = mPivotX + (pivotX - mPivotX) * (1 - scaleFactor);
        mPivotY = mPivotY + (pivotY - mPivotY) * (1 - scaleFactor);
    }

    this.invalidate();
}

public void release()
{
    if(mScaleFactor < MIN_SCALE)
    {
        final float startScaleFactor = mScaleFactor;

        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
            {
                scale(startScaleFactor + (MIN_SCALE - startScaleFactor)*interpolatedTime,mPivotX,mPivotY);
            }
        };

        a.setDuration(300);
        startAnimation(a);
    }
    else if(mScaleFactor > MAX_SCALE)
    {
        final float startScaleFactor = mScaleFactor;

        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
            {
                scale(startScaleFactor + (MAX_SCALE - startScaleFactor)*interpolatedTime,mPivotX,mPivotY);
            }
        };

        a.setDuration(300);
        startAnimation(a);
    }
}
```

and rewrote the OnPinchListener class like this

```
private class OnPinchListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{
    float currentSpan;
    float startFocusX;
    float startFocusY;

    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        currentSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
        startFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
        startFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        ZoomableRelativeLayout zoomableRelativeLayout= (ZoomableRelativeLayout) ImageFullScreenActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imageWrapper);

        zoomableRelativeLayout.relativeScale(detector.getCurrentSpan() / currentSpan, startFocusX, startFocusY);

        currentSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();

        return true;
    }

    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        ZoomableRelativeLayout zoomableRelativeLayout= (ZoomableRelativeLayout) ImageFullScreenActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imageWrapper);

        zoomableRelativeLayout.release();
    }
}
```

The original answer would reset the scale every time the touch event ended, but like this you can zoom in and out multiple times.

Comment: How should I define MAX_SCALE and MIN_SCALE?

Comment: I suggest using 1.0f for MIN_SCALE. I used 20.0f on MAX_SCALE, but this depends on what you want to do.

Comment: It's a timeline for a video editor and I want users be able to zoom in and out vertically and horizontally. So I should find the write number for MIN_SCALE and MAX_SCALE experimentally, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that would be for the best.

Comment: how do i pass the relative layout to ZoomableRelativeLayout?

Answer (score 3):

for fragments you just need to pass getActivity() instead of Activity Name

```java
final ZoomLayout zoomlayout = (ZoomLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoomLayout);
zoomlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        zoomlayout.init(getActivity());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working for me. No compilation errors and no crash but pinch to zoom just do nothing. I'm using it in a fragment just the way it describes here. Any help?

Comment: @Ashish Kumar Pal pinch to zoom not working .@Diego Perez  did u got answer?