# Android how to Apply Pinch zoom in Linear layout?

Tags: android, zooming, android-linearlayout

i am facing one issue, i want to Implement pinch zoom in linear layout.

Here is the Xml for linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backimage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/load"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" /> 

 </LinearLayout>
```

in problematically add some data to my linear layout `(@+id/load)` , But i want how to add zoom functionality to my linear layout Any one have idea of this. give me some suggestion.

here onTouch() function

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:   

                    if (zoom) {                      
                        // Log.d("detecting","inside the action pointer up");
                        float distY = detector.claculateDistanceY(event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                        // for horizontal zoom
                        float finalX1 = Math.min(event.getX(0), event.getX(1));
                        pointNo1 = (int) (BitmapDetector.prevX1 / loadWaveFormManager.getPointDistance());
                        pointNo1 = loadWaveFormManager.getPreStart() + pointNo1;

                        float finalX2 = Math.max(event.getX(0), event.getX(1));
                        pointNo2 = (int) (BitmapDetector.prevX2 / loadWaveFormManager.getPointDistance());
                        pointNo2 = loadWaveFormManager.getPreStart()+ pointNo2;

                        // Log.d("detecting","zoom points calculated");
                        distX = detector.claculateDistanceX(finalX1, finalX2);                          

                        if (Math.abs(distX) <= Math.abs(distY)) {
                            // Log.d("detecting","distanceX is less than that of Y");
                            if ((loadWaveFormManager.getZoom() + distY) > 30) {
                                // Log.d("detecting","setting the paramenter for vertical zoom");
                                if (distY > 100) {
                                    distY /= 3;
                                }

                                int tempZoom = (int) (loadWaveFormManager.getZoom() + distY);
                                loadWaveFormManager.setZoom(tempZoom); 
                            }
                        } else {         

                            if (distX > 0) {
                                zoomIn = true;
                            }
                            if (distX < 0) {
                                zoomIn = false;
                            }

                            distX += BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom;
                            float maxZoomDist = ((float) StaticValues.screenWidth / (float) 100.0);
                            float minZoomDist = (float) StaticValues.screenWidth / (float) StaticValues.RecordLength;
                            float zoomDistRate = (float) (maxZoomDist - minZoomDist) / (float) StaticValues.RecordLength;
                            zoomDist = zoomDistRate * distX;
                            numberOfPointToDraw = 0;

                            if (zoomIn && BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom < StaticValues.RecordLength) {
                                // Log.d("detecting","going to calculate the zoom in factors");
                                if (zoomDist >= maxZoomDist) {
                                    // Log.d("detecting","case of max zoom");
                                    zoomDist = maxZoomDist;
                                    numberOfPointToDraw = (int) (StaticValues.screenWidth / zoomDist);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setStart(pointNo1);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setLimit(pointNo1 + 100);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPreStart(loadWaveFormManager.getStart());
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPreLimit(loadWaveFormManager.getLimit());
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPointDistance(zoomDist);
                                    BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom = StaticValues.RecordLength; 
                                } else {
                                    // Log.d("detecting","not a case of max zoom");
                                    numberOfPointToDraw = (int) (StaticValues.screenWidth / zoomDist);
                                    // Log.d("zooming points","number fo points to draw:"+numberOfPointToDraw);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPointDistance(zoomDist);
                                    if (Math.abs(pointNo2 - pointNo1) < numberOfPointToDraw) {
                                        // Log.d("detecting","zooming area does not have sifficent points");
                                        while (Math.abs(pointNo1 - pointNo2) <= numberOfPointToDraw) {
                                            if (pointNo1 > 0)
                                                pointNo1--;
                                            if (pointNo2 < StaticValues.RecordLength)
                                                pointNo2++;
                                            // Log.d("detecting","cycling for stuffing the points: pointno1:"+pointNo1+"pointno2"+pointNo2+"difference-"+Math.abs(pointNo1-pointNo2)+"numberOfPointToDraw:"+numberOfPointToDraw);
                                        }
                                        // Log.d("detecting","stuffing the point of zooming area");
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setStart(pointNo1);
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setLimit(pointNo2);
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setPreStart(loadWaveFormManager.getStart());
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setPreLimit(loadWaveFormManager.getLimit());
                                        BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom = distX;
                                        // Log.d("zoom","inside Limit ZoomDist:"+zoomDist+" max Zoom Dist:"+maxZoomDist+" Start point:"+pointNo1+" End point:"+pointNo2);
                                    } else if (Math.abs(pointNo2 - pointNo1) > numberOfPointToDraw) {
                                        // Log.d("detecting","Zoom area have move then point required");
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setStart(pointNo1);
                                        pointNo2 = pointNo1+ numberOfPointToDraw;
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setLimit(pointNo2);
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setPreStart(loadWaveFormManager.getStart());
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setPreLimit(loadWaveFormManager.getLimit());
                                        BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom = distX;
                                        // Log.d("warning","inside Limit ZoomDist:"+zoomDist+" max Zoom Dist:"+maxZoomDist+" Start point:"+pointNo1+" End point:"+pointNo2);
                                    } else {
                                        // Log.d("detecting","zooming area have exactly same number of points");
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setStart(pointNo1);
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setLimit(pointNo2);
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setPreStart(loadWaveFormManager.getStart());
                                        loadWaveFormManager.setPreLimit(loadWaveFormManager.getLimit());
                                        BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom = distX; 
                                    }
                                }

                            } else if (zoomIn == false  && BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom > 0) {                                

                                if (zoomDist <= minZoomDist) {
                                    zoomDist = minZoomDist;
                                    numberOfPointToDraw = (int) ((float) StaticValues.screenWidth / (float) zoomDist);
                                    pointNo1 = 0;
                                    pointNo2 = StaticValues.RecordLength;
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setStart(0);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setLimit(StaticValues.RecordLength);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPreStart(loadWaveFormManager.getStart());
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPreLimit(loadWaveFormManager.getLimit());
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPointDistance(zoomDist);
                                    BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom = 0; 

                                } else {                    

                                    numberOfPointToDraw = (int) (StaticValues.screenWidth / zoomDist);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPointDistance(zoomDist);
                                    while (Math.abs(pointNo1 - pointNo2) <= numberOfPointToDraw) {
                                        if (pointNo1 > 0)
                                            pointNo1--;
                                        if (pointNo2 < StaticValues.RecordLength)
                                            pointNo2++;
                                    }

                                    loadWaveFormManager.setStart(pointNo1);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setLimit(pointNo2);
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPreStart(loadWaveFormManager.getStart());
                                    loadWaveFormManager.setPreLimit(loadWaveFormManager.getLimit());
                                    BitmapDetector.prevHoriZoom = distX;                                    
                                }
                            } else {

                            }                                   
                        }                        
                    }
```

Comment: Have you try onTouch() event??

Comment: Possible to Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch

Comment: @RaJeNdRa using that method only but after some time ui not responding ..

Comment: Can you show your code please if u have implemented??