# Show SQLite data in a WebView HTML table

Tags: java, android, html, webview, android-sqlite

[image: SQLite data for corresponding table]

[image: Table and id tags for each cell]

I'm writing an Android app (4.2 and above) to return the details of an item from a location on a warehouse shelf. 
The locations are fixed as an id for each cell of a HTML table. For example, the centre location has id="0,0". The HTML table is called from a WebView and will act as the GUI for the app. As such, I have three questions:

1. How can I get the HTML table to dynamically show the item for the corresponding record from the SQLite database?
2. How can I show the items on different shelves?
3. How would I make the cells selectable so that I can see further information about an item?

After a lot of searching, I've found posts on how to do this in Python, PHP and C, but nothing much in the way of doing it using Java/JavaScript.

As this is my first question, please let me know if you require any additional information. Cheers!

Comment: Is your sqlite databae inside the app or on a server? and why not using pure android and java to connect to database?

Comment: The database is inside the app. The main reason for having the SQLite data through the HTML table is purely to use pinch-zoom in the WebView, as each shelf is 24x24 cells.

Comment: check this question about zoomPinch a view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch