# How to zoom relative layout (contains images) in android?

Tags: java, android, zooming, android-relativelayout

I am developing an android app and I have set images on relative layout. Now I want to zoom the images through gestures (pan zoom) and the relative layout doesn't contain any imageview. The images are directly set on the relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in my openion its not a good practice to zoom the parent layout as it might create complications but you can find the possible solutions [zoom in/out RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch) and this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602) might help you in this regard.

Othere better solution to your problem can be you can create an `ImageView` with match_parent attributes and use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) to zoom the images, its amazing library for zooming the images, I am personally using it in my multiple projects.

This is the `ImageView` with `match_parent` attributes using `PhotoView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can find all the information about implementing the library [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

Hope it helps