# Android Zoomable endless rings

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create an endless zoomable rings, something like this -

[image]

Whenever a user pinch zooms, new small circle at the center is created and the outer circle grows bigger. I am using [pinch zoom in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029320/1979347) to create the following effect, but not able to achieve it properly. I have created a repo for this, let me know if you can help
https://github.com/rohankandwal/zoomable-growing-circles

Update:-
Changed `dispatchDraw` method on the mentioned stackoverflow answer -

```
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    int strokeWidth = 4;  // or whatever
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    myPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);   //color.RED
    float radius = (float) (0.5 * (width + height) * 2.5);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 51; i=i+10) {
      canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, (radius) + mScaleFactor + i,
        myPaint);
    }
    canvas.save();
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
  }
```

This code allows circle to grow -

Original image without pinch zoom

[image: Image without zoom]

Image when pinch zoomed

[image: Image with zoom]

As you can see, zoom is working, but don't know how to create new circles when zoomed at certain level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, there is not much to change in your code

In the `OnPinchListener` :

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    // 1 : no zoom
    final float zoomLevel = detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan;
    zoomableRadarLayout.scale(zoomLevel, startFocusX, startFocusY);
    return true;
}
```

and in `ZoomableRadarLayout`  :

```
// current pinch
private float mScaleFactor = 1;
// previous pinches
private float mAccumulatedScaleFactor = 1;


protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...

    float radius = (float) (0.5 * (width + height) * 2.5);

    // space between circles
    int step = 10;
    // radius of the outer circle
    int outerRadius = (int) (radius * mScaleFactor * mAccumulatedScaleFactor);
    // radius of the inner circle
    int innerRadius = 0;

    for (int i = outerRadius; i >= innerRadius; i = i - step) {
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, i, myPaint);
    }

    ...

}

public void restore() {
    // add the ending pinch to the previous ones
    mAccumulatedScaleFactor = mAccumulatedScaleFactor * mScaleFactor;
    mScaleFactor = 1;
    this.invalidate();
}
```

By the way, if possible it is recommended to avoid creating drawing objects like `Paint` while drawing. e.g. put the creation in some init method.

Comment: This is just rough code as you might have seen so I haven't added coding standards or improvement.

The code looks pretty close to what I want only issue that scaling doesn't work properly with it. Let me know if you can help with it. I am trying on my own too.

Comment: I mean scaling guesture, it doesn't scale properly

Comment: seems a bit better now, the dispatchDraw is event simpler

Comment: Almost perfect, now, only issue, whenever we are starting pinch zoom again, the circles are becoming small and then animating.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you mean you want that the circles stay large when the gesture if finished, so you can start a new pinch to zoom further ?

Comment: Yes, I mean, it should start from where we ended it, no reset it.

Comment: ok, I've added a field to accumulate the pinches, instead of resetting each time

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach: calculate radius of inner circle (minimal radius) and then draw circles and increasing radius, while circle can be visible on screen (max radius is not grater than distance from center of screen to one of its corner). Try this custom view with `ScaleGestureDetector`:

```
public class ZoomableRingView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mDeltaRadius = 0;
    private final float mBaseRadius = 50;
    private float mPinchBaseRadius = mBaseRadius;
    private float mMinRadius = mBaseRadius;

    public ZoomableRingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableRingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableRingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableRingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        drawCircles(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    private void drawCircles(Canvas canvas) {
        int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

        int centerX = canvasWidth / 2;
        int centerY = canvasHeight / 2;

        float maxRadius = (float) Math.sqrt(centerX * centerX + centerY * centerY);
        int nCircles = (int) Math.ceil(maxRadius / mBaseRadius) + 1;

        // calculate radius change
        mMinRadius = mPinchBaseRadius + mDeltaRadius / 2;

        // bring radius to [0..2 * mBaseRadius] interval
        while (mMinRadius < 1f) {
            mMinRadius += 2 * mBaseRadius;
        }
        while (mMinRadius > 2 * mBaseRadius) {
            mMinRadius -= 2 * mBaseRadius;
        }

        // draw circles from min to max
        float radius = mMinRadius;
        for (int ixCircle = 0; ixCircle < nCircles; ixCircle++) {
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mPaint);
            radius += 2 * mBaseRadius;
        }
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        float startingSpan;

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mPinchBaseRadius = mMinRadius;
            startingSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mDeltaRadius = detector.getCurrentSpan() - startingSpan;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `activity.xml` with that custom view can be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/layout_channel1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}.ZoomableRingView
        android:id="@+id/zoomablering_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And you should get something like that:

[image: Infinite ring zoom]