# How to scale buttons positions according to scaling background imageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a problem with the synchronization of the location of buttons on top of the imageView - when the image stretched button remains in place. I want the buttons to move in synchronism in accordance with the imageView zoom (while keeping the aspect ratio).
[image]

On attached picture you may see problem. Buttons (icons [V]) remains theirs positions when i resize image by gesture. I want to automatically move buttons when image resizing and dragging.

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/floorPlanLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OrderActivity">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFloorPlan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/imageview_border_background">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is difficult to help you since I cannot understand what you desire. Can you please add an Image of the result you want. it will become much easier for not only me but for everyone else.

Comment: I try to explain more clearly. Please see attached picture -  icons marked [V] (which is buttons) keep theirs positions while image resizing, but i want that buttons will be move to new positions according to image size.

Comment: Seems like this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch . Set the Image as the background of the RelativeLayout and put the Icons in the layout.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are saved my time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case its better to use layout with background than imageview (thanks to  [Daksh Agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083135/daksh-agrawal)). When i reviewed more about proposed solution ([Android - zoom in/out RelativeLayout with spread/pinch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch)) i found that its not quite flexible for me. After a little search i found that: https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout. Its several utilities which help to zoom and pan Layout and imageView very easy. Hope it helps someone.